# prevent info path web based form from printing?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath

i design web based Form using infopath 2010 (no data base ) published on sharepoint 2007

can i prevent user from printing form unless user fill all form text boxes?

Comment: I don't worry about Print Screen, all forms too long and we denied print screen for users.

the issue is: forms is customer sign ... a lot of issues comes from sign forms with some fields not filled

make fields ( can't be blank ) prevent it from saving not printing, so we need any solution to prevent printing unless user fill all required fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not available option on web browser forms

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0abfab8-2877-4b17-a76c-6d06eb052db9/restriction-printing-for-infopath-web-browser-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prevent the user from using his computer.

What if the user just takes a screen shot then prints the screen shot?

What if the user just takes a picture of the screen with his cell phone camera?

The computer belongs to the user, not to you.

Comment: sure but users print form and fill it manually (easy way ) and we need him to fill it on screen then print it ... Thanks

Comment: Then fire them if they do it wrong. Not every problem has a technological solution.

Comment: when you handle 5000 user, more than 140 branch and department its to hard to ask all of them to follow honor code or fire them :)   kindly find this :  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0abfab8-2877-4b17-a76c-6d06eb052db9/restriction-printing-for-infopath-web-browser-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy